# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, error

I am obtaining this error in only one site collection. In:

- User.aspx
- Trying to add site collection administrator
- Or editing any person column in any list

¿Any help? thanks!!!

> 08/24/2016 14:36:31.12        w3wp.exe (0x13EC)
>   0x2354    SharePoint Foundation         Runtime
>   tkau                Unexpected
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No se puede completar
>   esta acción.  Vuelva a intentarlo.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateMembers(String
>   bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId,
>   Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl,
>   UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32
>   lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)        9b34e43e-4ca3-4cb2-bd36-981a3491c605

Comment: do you have the user profile service up & running?

Comment: Not sure, how can I check it?

Comment: go to your farm Central Administration -> Application Management -> (under Service Applications) click Services on Server -> then Select the server in your farm where you have provisioned your User Profile Services -> Then check that: User Profile Service & User Profile Synchronization Service are Started

Comment: It is stopped. It is development envirnment.

Comment: here we had a similar issue a few years ago, and no matter it's dev environment the services had to be running, why don't you try to start them?

Comment: I am calling the administrator to try. The strange thing it is only ocurreing in one site collection. If I create onother SC in same WA, no problem...

Comment: user profile service service solved, but problem not solved. Any idea?

Comment: is it the same error in your trace correlation log?

Comment: same error, yesy